# Regex – Get string after a character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code which works for getting the part of the string BEFORE a character (in my case the character is ":")

```
var getMinutes = value.match(/([\d.]+) *:/)[1];
```

I need to make it work for getting the part of string after ":" too but im stuck

Comment: Add another capture group after the `:`.

Comment: please give us some examples with desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the capture group to after the `:`

```
var getSeconds = value.match(/[\d.]+ *:([\d.]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try split. For example:
value = "123:456" => value.split(":")[0] will return "123" while value.split(":")[1] will return "456"